# Connecting Highcharts to a database using ASP.net

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, razor, highcharts

I've been trying to connect my highcharts graph to a database so I could have live data. The table I've been trying to connect is called dbo.Answers_int. I've been having trouble. I based my code off this website https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/1f3f2a/charting-in-mvc/

When I try to load the page, highcharts doesn't even come up. I'm out of ideas. Any help would be appreciated.

ReportsController.cs:

```
    public class ReportsController : Controller{
    private HHDBEntities db = new HHDBEntities();

    public static DataTable GetQuestionSummary()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable("ChartSummary");
        string query = "Select QuestionAns From [dbo].[Answers_int]";
        string connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SampleMembershipDB"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connString);
        //con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=.;" + "Initial Catalog=Transport;" + "Persist Security Info=True;";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = query;
        //cmd.Connection = con;
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        con.Open();
        da.Fill(dt);
        con.Close();
        return dt;

    }
    public class Summary
    {
        public double Item { get; set; }
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }

    public JsonResult ChartSummary()
    {
        List<Summary> lstSummary = new List<Summary>();

        foreach (DataRow dr in GetQuestionSummary().Rows)
        {
            Summary summary = new Summary();
            summary.Value = dr[0].ToString().Trim();
            summary.Item = Convert.ToDouble(dr[1]);
            lstSummary.Add(summary);

        }
        return Json(lstSummary.ToList(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

PieChart.cshtml:

```
    $(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'Reports/PieChart',
            dataType: "json",
            type: "GET",
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            async: false,
            processData: false,
            cache: false,
            delay: 15,
            success: function (data) {
                // alert(data);
                var series = new Array();
                for (var i in data) {
                    var serie = new Array(data[i].Value, data[i].Item);
                    series.push(serie);
                }
                DrawPieChart(series);
            },
            error: function (xhr) {
                alert('error');
            }
        });
    });
    function DrawPieChart(series) {
        $('#container').highcharts({

            chart: {
                plotBackgroundColor: null,
                plotBorderWidth: 1, //null,
                plotShadow: false
            },
            title: {
                text: ' Vehicle Summary'
            },
            tooltip: {
                pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
            },
            plotOptions: {
                pie: {
                    allowPointSelect: true,
                    cursor: 'pointer',
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: false
                    },
                    showInLegend: true
                }
            },
            series: [{
                type: 'pie',
                name: 'Task Status',
                data: series
            }]
        });
    }
```

Comment: `class ReportsController` is missing a closing brace. is that just a typo?

Answer (score 0):

You are only getting one column from the database. You'll see in the example that 2 columns are being returned, and one of them is a calculation that returns a percentage. It looks like you will need this to create the graph.

And in this section

```
foreach (DataRow dr in GetQuestionSummary().Rows)
{
    Summary summary = new Summary();
    summary.Value = dr[0].ToString().Trim();
    summary.Item = Convert.ToDouble(dr[1]);
    lstSummary.Add(summary);    
}
```

you can see that an Item and a Value are needed. Again, you need 2 columns of data to work with.